# Controlling the process allocation to a processor

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, fork, multicore

Does `fork` always create a process in a separate processor?

Is there a way, I could control the forking to a particular processor. For example, if I have 2 processors and want the `fork` to create a parallel process but in the same processor that contains the `parent`. Does NodeJS provide any method for this? I am looking for a control over the allocation of the processes. ... Is this even a good idea?

Also, what are the maximum number of processes that could be forked and why?

Comment: Can’t answer whether it’s a good idea without knowing why you want to do it in the first place. Stuff like https://github.com/saquibkhan/nodeaffinity exists, though.

Comment: @Ryan _Why I want to do this:_ I think, it is because of the incomplete understanding of how NodeJS handles `fork`.

Comment: So you’re saying you don’t have a reason to want to run child processes on the same core anymore?

Comment: @Ryan I want to understand how is everything being handled and do I have a way with NodeJS to directly control these allocations.

Comment: Why do you want to specify which core your process runs on?

Comment: @Ryan No business requirement. Just want to experiment and play around.

Comment: Okay, well, the package I linked to above will set a process’s CPU affinity.

Answer (score 0):

I've no Node.js wisdom to impart, simply some info on what OSes generally do.

Any modern OS will schedule processes / threads on CPUs and cores according to the prevailing burden on the machine. The whole point is that they're very good at this, so one is going to have to try very hard to come up with scheduling / core affinity decisions that beat the OS. Almost no one bothers. Unless you're running on very specific hardware (which perhaps, perhaps one might get to understand very well), you're having to make a lot of complex decisions for every single different machine the code runs on.

If you do want to try then I'm assuming that you'll have to dig deep below node.JS to make calls to the underlying C library. Most OSes (including Linux) provide means for a process to control core affinity (it's exposed in Linux's glibc).